# Sites where you are not joined onto the site need padding for Post as Guest

Tags: bug, design

When you are not joined to a particular community on the stackexchange network and you click on a question then you have the option to log in or `Post as guest`.  These divs need a bit of padding as they are too close to one another:

[image]

These boxes are too close to one another.  Please add `padding-left:45px;` to the second div (Post as a guest).  This will give it some room:

[image]